# WorkflowInspectionServices.GetActivities from "SubWorkflows"

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I am getting an error running this code.

```
IEnumerable<Activity> activityList = WorkflowInspectionServices.GetActivities(activityCurrent);


if (activityList.Count() <= 0)
```

I have a number of workflow that I want to go through it's activities. I have no problem meanwhile the activities that I use in the workflows are code activities or native activities. The problem comes when I use another workflow in the workflow (I hope I am making sense with that)

The error is in the `activityList.Count()` which is Cannot create unknown type '`{clr-namespace:....PhysicalInbound}`Destination'.

Actually it works if I put the content of the "subworkflow" in the "Parent" workflow. My guess it is that have to do with the imports but I have not been able to figure it out so far : S

StackTrace:

```
   at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteStartObject(XamlType xamlType)
   at System.Xaml.XamlServices.Transform(XamlReader xamlReader, XamlWriter xamlWriter, Boolean closeWriter)
   at System.Activities.XamlIntegration.FuncDeferringLoader.FuncFactory`1.Evaluate()
   at System.Activities.DynamicActivity.OnInternalCacheMetadata(Boolean createEmptyBindings)
   at System.Activities.Activity.InternalCacheMetadata(Boolean createEmptyBindings, IList`1& validationErrors)
   at System.Activities.ActivityUtilities.ProcessActivity(ChildActivity childActivity, ChildActivity& nextActivity, Stack`1& activitiesRemaining, ActivityCallStack parentChain, IList`1& validationErrors, ProcessActivityTreeOptions options, ProcessActivityCallback callback)
   at System.Activities.ActivityUtilities.ProcessActivityTreeCore(ChildActivity currentActivity, ActivityCallStack parentChain, ProcessActivityTreeOptions options, ProcessActivityCallback callback, IList`1& validationErrors)
   at System.Activities.ActivityUtilities.CacheRootMetadata(Activity activity, LocationReferenceEnvironment hostEnvironment, ProcessActivityTreeOptions options, ProcessActivityCallback callback, IList`1& validationErrors)
   at System.Activities.WorkflowInspectionServices.<GetActivities>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Thanks for your time,

Joan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. In my case it was because I put both Parent workflow and "subworkflows" in the same assembly.

If it is your case, try putting them in another assembly as you do with activities.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of how the XAML services facade is designed. You need to set LocalAssembly on the ReaderSettings. The reason is that the readers & builders shouldn't assume which assembly is considered local within the XAML because it may and probably have been developed in a different assembly then the one loading the workflow.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bfbc0c01-7205-4fb4-8b3a-260c9d6db37f/loading-file-with-activityxamlservicesload-does-not-resolve-references-activities?forum=wfprerelease

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0086f55d-3ed1-4015-90ca-ad8144178255/why-can-i-not-load-a-workflow-using-activityxamlservicesload-when-it-contains-a-custom-activity?forum=wfprerelease